# Got metamask connection disconnect when sending a transaction

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

I am building a dapp with web3 and call smart contract running in sepolia testnet. I have below code to send transaction:

```
provider.request({
        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params: [
          {
            from: account.address,
            to:address,
            gasPrice: BigInt(gasPrice),
            gasLimit: Number(gas) * 2,
            nonce: Number(await w.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address)),
            value: BigInt(price),
            data: await myContract.methods
              .createSector(
                web3.utils.toBigInt(selectedCells[0].globalI),
                web3.utils.toBigInt(selectedCells[0].globalJ),
                web3.utils.toBigInt(1),
                web3.utils.toBigInt(1)
              )
              .encodeABI(),
          },
        ],
      });
```

when run this method, I got below error on chrome console. It seems the netmask connection is disconnected for some reasons. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

```
MetaMask: Content script lost connection to "MetaMask Background Multiplex". Error: PortDuplexStream - disconnected
  at i._write (contentscript.js:10:35651)
  at contentscript.js:10:91133
  at C (contentscript.js:10:91201)
  at I.write (contentscript.js:10:94547)
  at t.exports.g (contentscript.js:19:19782)
  at a.emit (contentscript.js:10:32896)
  at _ (contentscript.js:19:14585)
  at w (contentscript.js:19:14400)
  at v.push (contentscript.js:19:15211)
  at a._write (contentscript.js:19:3478)

MetaMask: Muxed traffic for channel "metamask-provider" failed. undefined
contentscript.js:1 MetaMask: Muxed traffic between channels "provider" and "metamask-provider" failed. undefined
contentscript.js:1 MetaMask: Muxed traffic for channel "publicConfig" failed.
```